# Using Mandelstam Variables in Experimental Data

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics

I am reading [an article of Veltman and Lemoine](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321380905210?via%3Dihub) from 1980 on radiative corrections to $e^+ e^- \rightarrow W^+ W^- $ in the Weinberg model.

In Section 3, they work at tree level and write down the appropriate matrix elements as functions of the Mandelstam variables $s$ and $t$.  These functions are used to derive the differential cross section which is plotted against scattering angle in the centre of mass frame for several values of energy.

I see that the energy comes from the Mandelstam variable $s$ (since $s$ is the square of the centre of mass energy), but how is the value of $t$ decided in these plots?  $t$ is the square of the four-momentum transferred in the process, so is it related to the scattering angle?

Edit: OK I think I know now, I will leave the question if it benefits anyone else (answer posted below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be the mass of $W$ and let $m$ be electron mass.

In the center of mass frame we have
\begin{align*}
p_1&=\underset{\text{inbound $e^-$}}
{\begin{pmatrix}E\\0\\0\\p\end{pmatrix}}
\\[1ex]
p_2&=\underset{\text{inbound $e^+$}}
{\begin{pmatrix}E\\0\\0\\-p\end{pmatrix}}
\\[1ex]
p_3&=\underset{\text{outbound $W^-$}}
{\begin{pmatrix}
E\\
\rho\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
\rho\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}}
\\[1ex]
p_4&=
\underset{\text{outbound $W^+$}}
{
\begin{pmatrix}
E\\
-\rho\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
-\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
-\rho\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}}
\end{align*}

where $E$ is beam energy and
\begin{equation*}
p=\sqrt{E^2-m^2},\quad
\rho=\sqrt{E^2-M^2}
\end{equation*}

The Mandelstam variables are
\begin{align*}
s&=(p_1+p_2)^2=4E^2
\\
t&=(p_1-p_3)^2=-2E^2+M^2+m^2+2p\rho\cos\theta
\\
u&=(p_1-p_4)^2=-2E^2+M^2+m^2-2p\rho\cos\theta
\end{align*}

Approximating electron mass with $m=0$ we have
\begin{align*}
t&=-2E^2+M^2+2E\rho\cos\theta
\\
u&=-2E^2+M^2-2E\rho\cos\theta
\end{align*}

Let
\begin{equation*}
\beta=\frac{\rho}{E}=\frac{\sqrt{E^2-M^2}}{E},
\quad
\beta^2=1-\frac{M^2}{E^2}
\end{equation*}

Then
\begin{align*}
t&=-E^2\left(1+\beta^2-2\beta\cos\theta\right)
\\
u&=-E^2\left(1+\beta^2+2\beta\cos\theta\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that $t$ can be written in terms of the scattering angle $\theta$.

In the centre of mass frame, if $t = (k-p)^2$, a quick calculation shows that

$t = - 2p^2 ( 1 - \cos \theta).$

If one knows the incoming four-momentum $p$, then the numerical value of $t$ is determined by the angle of scattering in the centre of mass frame.

Edit: This is also answered in the paper, since they show that when the masses are different, $t$ can be written as an expression

$t  = M^2 - \frac{1}{2}s ( 1 + \beta \cos \theta),$

where $M$ is the mass of the W boson and $\beta$ depends on $s$.